# Codeigniter file upload and resize

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, resize

I'm uploading profile pictures to my website and the first upload is working fine, but when I try and resize the image and reupload it to the same folder it breaks. From testing, I know it is going through the array and it is inserting the data into the database, but just not re-saving into the folder.

This is what I have going one.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['file_name'] = $this->user->pen_name.'.jpg';
$config['file_path'] = './uploads/'.$this->user->pen_name.'.jpg';
$config['max-size'] = 2000;
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;
$config['max_width'] = 2000;
$config['max_height'] = 3000;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}else{
    $resize['source_image'] = base_url().'/uploads/'.$config['file_name'];
    $resize['new_image'] = './uploads/';
    $resize['file_path'] = './uploads/'.$this->user->pen_name.'.jpg';
    $resize['create_thumb'] = false;
    $resize['maintain_ratio'] = true;
    $resize['width'] = 200;
    $resize['height'] = 300;
    $resize['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->load->library('upload', $resize);
    $this->users_model->uploadPic($resize['file_path']);
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same issue, and solved it as follows:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('logoUpload')) {
    $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'));
    //error
} else {

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    //resize:

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 150;
    $config['height']   = 50;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    //add to the DB
    $this->settings_model->upload_logo($upload_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the default config from codeigniter, just put unlink at the end:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 75;
$config['height'] = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();

//remove original file
@unlink( $config['source_image'] );
```

Comment: Sorry for this, you can get it from [here](http://www.filedropper.com/thumb). And create uploads/cache in core folder, where index.php stays. Usage: <img src="/thumb/view/w/640/h/480/src/images/example.jpg" alt="Example" />. thumb.php is controller

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something here. I was not looking for a thumb generator, I was simply looking to resize an image that a user uploads so if they upload an image that is huge it will be reduced and I won't be hosting or cashing the larger image.

Comment: That is not working though, that was what I was basing my code off originally. It's not uploading the resized image just the original one.