# I am unable to resize my image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 100;
    $config['height'] = 150;
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

> I am unable to resize image ... please give me my mistake

Comment: first initialize and then resize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218247/codeigniter-image-resize and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949983/codeigniter-file-upload-and-resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the @jigar Shah comment you have to first initalize upload library before resize

```
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
            $config['allowed_types'] ='csv|xls|xlsx';
            $config['max_size'] = 1024;  //in KB
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_filename'] = 25;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_name')) {
                //if file upload failed then catch the errors
                $this->handle_error($this->upload->display_errors());
                $is_file_error = TRUE;
            } else {
                 //store the file info
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 150;
                $config['height'] = 100;
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    $this->handle_error($this->image_lib->display_errors());
                }
            }
```

For more reference please [visit](http://www.roytuts.com/upload-and-resize-image-using-codeigniter)